# LINQ subquery "NOT IN" problem

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I do not understand why this query fails.

```
var qTags = from tagsU in _context.ADN_ProductTagsView
where !(from o in _context.ADN_ProductTagsView
        where o.ProductID == productId
         select o.ProductTagID).Contains(tagsU.ProductTagID)
select tagsU;
```

Or this one:

```
var tagAux = from o in _context.ADN_ProductTagsView
             where o.ProductID == productId
             select o.ProductTagID;

var qTags = from tagus in _context.ADN_ProductTagsView
            where !tagAux.Contains(tagus.ProductTagID)
            select tagus ;
```

Both give me this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Int32](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: EF under .NET 3.5 sucks. Move to .NET 4.0 and your problem will be gone.

Comment: EF just sucks in general, but he doesn't need to upgrade to fix this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the implementation of the QueryProvider you're using isn't complete. I'm not familiar with the QueryProvider you're using, but maybe you can try something like this:

```
var qTags = from tagsU in _context.ADN_ProductTagsView
where !(from o in _context.ADN_ProductTagsView
        where o.ProductID == productId
         select o.ProductTagID).Any(tagId => tagId == tagsU.ProductTagID)
select tagsU;
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Try .Any

```
var qTags = from tagus in _context.ADN_ProductTagsView
            where !tagAux.Any(t=> t== tagus.ProductTagID)
            select tagus ;
```

btw, did not run the query, so please check the syntax.